# Center Text when using drawableBottom

Tags: android

I am using the following method

setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,null,drawable) in the TextView that I have. The drawable is below the text but the problem is that it starts where the text starts. Is there a way I can set it so the text that is above the image is centered horizontally?

For example, instead of

```
Sample Text
----------------
|              |
|              |  
----------------
```

Do it so it appears like that

```
  Sample Text
----------------
|              |
|              |  
----------------
```

PS: I know I can use Layout with TextView and ImageView and align them but I am trying to use only TextView  but itself to show the the text and the image

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Hello Android" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Output looks like this,

[image]